# How to escape '@' in vscode regexp for syntax highlighting

Tags: visual-studio-code, escaping, syntax-highlighting

I'm wanting to highlight strings for a programming language used in the Reaper DAW. The strings will look like the following @init @slider.

When I try include the '@' symbol in the regxp, the syntax highlighting fails. I've tried to escape it using '\@' as shown below, but this doesn't help.

```
{
    "name": "keyword.eel2",
    "match": "\\b(\@init|\@slider|\@block|\@sample|\@gfx)\\b"
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

I believe the issue is that `\b` will only match at word boundaries, and the chraracters that constitute a word for this purpose do not include `@`.

That means your regular expression would only match text that starts with a word—such as `a@init`—and not text that start with a space or new line. Try removing the leading `\b` or changing it to something else such as any space character (`\s`).

Comment: Thanks so much for your reply! I will give this a try tomorrow and get back to you